# How are BLKIDs Assigned?

Tags: linux, hardware, uuid

Suppose I have a situation like I have installed /etc and /boot in two separate partition which belongs to an USB device , and the rest of the system / and /home in the HDD. Now my question is I need to statically route the USB device in my fstab , but the problem is there is no certainty that the USB will always take say /dev/sdb or /dev/sdc, so my approach would be to use BLKID.

Here I am confused as to whether the BLKID of a particular Hardware Device (with a static Hardware ID) always the same? if not what is the work around in the situation?

How are BLKIDs Assigned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUID's (which you can see by running `blkid`) are assigned to a filesystem when you create it (e.g. when you run `mkfs.ext4` or `mkswap`). Mounting by UUID is appropriate for what you want to do.

Comment: OK I format the USB in Ext4 using mkfs.ext4 in one system , And I want to mount it permanently in another system using UUID in fstab. Will the USB always mount without a problem?

Comment: Yes, assuming there's no unrelated problem.